# Is there a difference between google play app install vs local install on an Android Device?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, sharedpreferences, xamarin.essentials

Is there a difference between **Google Play install** vs **local install** on an Android Device?

I have a Google Play installed application and which is set up and in use, so Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences are setup. I then installed an update to that application from the beta track. Upon starting the app, Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences are not being picked up.

I had to change the keys associated with the preferences compared to the old version of the application. The new version application, on start, updates the keys and continues as normal.

I know the update code works as expected, as when the app is installed locally from an apk (not from google play), it works as expected when the updated apk is installed.

Basically, what I want to know is:

1. Does Google Play Services / Play Store, remove Xamarin.Essentials.Preferences at install/update? Does this only occur on the beta track?
2. Is there a solution to this issue? I would like to keep the end-user from having to reconfigure/re-login to the app on an update.

Comment: In general,your application data will be remain when user install updates.But it must be with the same package name to detect as an update of previous App.And make sure your APK is the same signature.

Comment: The signing and package name are the same.